# Blank image imagecreatefromjpeg

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have the following function

```
function getImage($imageHash,$script) {



        $imageurl = "http://www.MYURL.com/images/images/ABImage_clock_4.jpg";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imageurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($data);

        // draw lines

        $num_lines = rand(6,10);


            for ($i = 0; $i <= $num_lines; $i++)
            {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($img, rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255));

        imageline($img, rand(5,95), rand(5,95), rand(5,95), rand(5,95), $color);
    }

    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, rand(1, 50), rand(1, 50), rand(1, 50));

    imagejpeg($img, '', 30);
    imagedestroy($img);

    }
```

But it seems like the image wont be created. The image is in the root folder as you can see images/images folder. But nothing will make the image be visible as it should.

[image]

How can i fix this?

UPDATE:

a dump from `$data`
[image]

UPDATE2:

[image]

LINES:
42: `

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($data);
```

51:

```
$color = imagecolorallocate($img, rand(0,255), rand(0,255),` rand(0,255));
```

and 58 & 59:`

```
    imagejpeg($img, '', 30);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is NOT an answer, but I cannot write this in the comment section.]

I think it is impossible to answer without seeing how you call this code.

A few ideas:

1) Start by dumping $data somewhere (Your browser, a file, whatever), to see if your curl call worked as expected.

*2) The second argument in (imagejpeg($img, '', 30);) is an empty string? That should contain the path to the location where you want to safe the image. And also the name.*

(Poster wants it outputted to the browser directly)

Edit:

OK, The data is fetched via curl. Good.

Now you output it directly to the browser, right?

In that case make sure that you use the right mime-type.

So, from your HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.yoursite.com/myImageGenerator.php">
```

And make sure your add the right headers to your php script.

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Also make sure you don't output anything else.

===================

Next edit (because those comments are too small)

**Situation: You have now an image that shows that your have a missing image.**

That doesn't help at all, of course. ;-)

Did you check for any errors thrown out by your script? It can be hard to debug imagecreating scripts because the errors cannot be seen on screen.

You can do this in 2 ways:

1) Check you error logs. Use phpinfo() http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php and look up the location of your errorlog, and look into it.

2) I prefer this one: Simply call your imagecreating script directly in your browser. Make sure you change back the mimetype in your PHP. Now you see the output the browser receives when trying to fetch the image AND any errors.

================================

Here you go, a working example based on Spongebob. (I don't have rights on the used picture. Wish I did.)

I expect you can use it to modify your own. Be sure to look up functions you don't know at www.php.net.

```
<?php
    // call this script with test.php?produceimage=Y to return only image
    $bPictMode = isset($_GET["produceimage"]);

    $imageurl = "http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/unanything/images/6/6a/Spongebob.jpg";

    if ($bPictMode){

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imageurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $img = imagecreatefromstring ($data);

        // draw lines
        $num_lines = rand(6,10);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $num_lines; $i++){
            $color = imagecolorallocate($img, rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255));
            imageline($img, rand(5,95), rand(5,95), rand(5,95), rand(5,95), $color);
        }
        imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, rand(1, 50), rand(1, 50), rand(1, 50));

        imagejpeg($img, NULL, 30);
        imagedestroy($img);
    } else {
        $imgURL = "test.php?produceimage=Y";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>jpg generator</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  Do you see him? (image-url = <?php echo $imgURL; ?>)<br>
  <img src="./<?php echo $imgURL; ?>" style="border: 3px solid blue;">
  <hr>  
 </body>
</html>
<?php   
    }
?>
```

Comment: Will do. http://prntscr.com/8r7ig8 worked there.

the purpose is it to draw lines on the image.

Comment: OK, that was part 1: You DO get a response from your curl call. Good so far.
I'll make an edit in my post about the rest.

Comment: Updated. yes. i got some errors. updated the main post.

Comment: Well, go fix them! I cannot help from here.

Comment: I posted a full example. Last thing in my post.